# Winform, How to suppress the winform error dialog?

Tags: c#

I have working on C# 4.0 winform project with Xulrunner and VLC web plugin,

Something the VLC will cause the winform crash, and show something like :

[image]

But i have a software monitor to restart the application when crash.

So how can i suppress this dialog? because something it will on top of the screen, even the application is restart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event.

Comment: When you handle the event you should probably display some sort of notification to the user. If you are using unmanaged code I would prefer to quit the application as the problem may be difficult to recover from and result in corruption of data.

Comment: I have create a handler : (static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)) in program.cs , but what to do next?? just try..catch the EventArgs???

Comment: The exception is already caught for you. You can check for it in the `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject` property, or just ignore it and do something else, like restart your app.

Comment: Thanks Mark, may i ask for more? How i can suppress the unhandled exception, but how can i suppress the "[PROGRAM NAME] is not response. Report to Microsoft" error dialog?? Because it seem the UnhandledException cannot handle this.

Comment: I'm not sure. You can post that as a separate question with more information and you'll probably get an answer.